# Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `c' or `c@'

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using the TikZ package to make a flowchart. I'm getting the following error: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `c' or`c@' (in '1c'). \node (in1) [input] {node};

I don't understand what the error is referring to. This is my code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}


\tikzstyle{question} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{diagnosis} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{input} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1c, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (in1) [input] {node};
\node (q1) [question, below of=in1] {Matches distractor node?};
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (q1);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `minimum height=1c` should be `minimum height=1cm`, methinks...

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! It would be great to see when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: off-topic but you may want to switch to the `\tikzset` syntax instead of `\tikzstyle`, e.g. `\tikzset{arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the `input` style. You have `minimum height=1c`. I think you mean `minimum height=1cm`:

```
\tikzstyle{input} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
```

---

Also, as Mr. marmot said, the `\tikzstyle` syntax is somewhat discouraged and [should be replaced by `\tikzset`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52379/134574):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzset{%
  question/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black},
% \tikzstyle{question} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
  diagnosis/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
% \tikzstyle{diagnosis} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
  input/.style={diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black},
% \tikzstyle{input} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
  arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
% \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (in1) [input] {node};
\node (q1) [question, below of=in1] {Matches distractor node?};
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (q1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I kept the previous syntax for comparison.

Comment: You are right. I feel very stupid now.

Comment: @Renate No worries, this happens for everyone :)